# Worklog entries of an JIRA-user needs to be fetched

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, jira-rest-api

I have 15 usernames with me, I need to pull worklog entries of these users and manipulate it from JAVA client

Below are the jar files am using to connect JIRA api and fetch values

[image]

The code is pasted below

```
public class JiraConnector {

JiraRestClient jira;

public JiraConnector() throws URISyntaxException {
    String url = prop().getUrl();
    String userName = prop().getUser() ;
    String password = prop().getpwd() ;
    JerseyJiraRestClientFactory clientFactory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
    jira = clientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI(url),
            userName, password);
    System.out.println("Connection established to >> " + url);
}

public void printIssueDetails(String jiraNumber) {
    System.out.println("JiraNumber is " + jiraNumber);
    Issue issue = jira.getIssueClient().getIssue(jiraNumber, null);

    System.out.println(issue.getSummary());
    System.out.println(issue.getDescription());
}

public void printUserWorkLog(String userName) {
    System.out.println("user details invoked ... ");
    User user = jira.getUserClient().getUser(userName, null);
    System.out.println(user.getDisplayName());
    System.out.println(user.getEmailAddress());

}
```

For any given username, am able to print his displayName and emailAdress (all those basic infos).

**But I need to get the list of worklogs for the given user**. Not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all worklog records for selected issue:

```
List<Worklog> worklogByIssue = ComponentAccessor.getWorklogManager().getByIssue(issue);
```

After that you can parse all worklog records to determine for what user this record created:

```
for (Worklog worklogByIssueItem : worklogByIssue)
{
   int timeSpent = worklogByIssueItem.getTimeSpent().intValue();
   String worklogAuthorName = worklogByIssueItem.getAuthorObject().getName();
   ...
}
```

And last task is search of issues by some params:

```
public static List<Issue> searchIssues(SearchParametersAggregator searchParams)
{
    String jqlQuery = searchParams.getJqlQuery();
    String projectId = searchParams.getProjectId();
    String condition = createCondition(jqlQuery, projectId);

    JqlQueryBuilder jqlQueryBuilder = prepareJqlQueryBuilder(condition);

    return searchIssues(jqlQueryBuilder);
}

static List<Issue> searchIssues(JqlQueryBuilder jqlQueryBuilder)
{
    Query query = jqlQueryBuilder.buildQuery();
    SearchService searchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(SearchService.class);
    try
    {
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getUser();
        User user = applicationUser.getDirectoryUser();
        SearchResults searchResults = searchService.search(user, query, PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter());
        List<Issue> issues = searchResults.getIssues();

        return issues;
    }
    catch (SearchException e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurs during search of issues");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ArrayList<Issue>();
}

static JqlQueryBuilder prepareJqlQueryBuilder(String condition)
{
    try
    {
        Query query = jqlQueryParser.parseQuery(condition);
        JqlQueryBuilder builder = JqlQueryBuilder.newBuilder(query);

        return builder;
    }
    catch (JqlParseException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("JqlParseException during parsing jqlQuery!");
    }
}
```

Comment: With an issue, you are pulling the worklog .. Am asking on, how to pull the worklog for a user for the specified date range

Comment: You need to write your util to extract worklog for user and specified date range from all worklog records

Comment: Or you can play with JQL condition to get your data (see method prepareJqlQueryBuilder())

Comment: How do you get the "ComponentAccessor"? What dependency is that?