# Get JIRA worklog for the given user using JAVA REST client

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

How to get worklog for an user ??

I have a JAVA rest client which would connect to JIRA server and get data like "Project", "USER info", "Project Info"

But I would like to get worklog for an user.

1.) Provide userName

2.) Get list of workLogs

Can some one help on this ? Please

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer to your previous question: [Worklog entries of an JIRA-user needs to be fetched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472620/worklog-entries-of-an-jira-user-needs-to-be-fetched/24653831#24653831)
Here I provide source code to get worklog records for each user.

Comment: With an issue, you are pulling the worklog .. Am asking on, how to pull the worklog for a user for the specified date range

Comment: I put answer to main thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472620/worklog-entries-of-an-jira-user-needs-to-be-fetched/24653831#24653831